# how to bind an assembly when it is not in the same folder as main .exe using its relative address?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, assemblybinding

I added these lines into app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas?microsoft?com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"
          href= ".\libs\CrashReporter.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But my console application crashes and exception says that:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'CrashReporter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
at TestConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

CrashReporter.dll is a managed code in c# that I have referenced in my consol application. But in properties tab of dll reference I have set `Copy Local` to false. Because in installer I want to copy it in .\libs\CrashReporter.dll folder and that would not be in the same folder as .exe file.

**How can I tell the .net that i places the dll file in ../libs/ folder relative to the .exe file?**

Comment: Did you add it through references? Is this you dll? is this managed dll? Is this library available through nuget? if so you, you should consider installing it by nuget

Comment: @Piotr  this is a dll of mine. and it is managed code. If i copy it to bin folder everything works fine. but I need it to be in a different folder.

Comment: You mustn't copy it yourself. Just add reference to it using References-> Add reference -> Browse -> Click Browser button and locate this dll (in lib folder)

Comment: @Piotr I have created a setup file and in that setup i copy the crashreporter to a shared folder which other applications can use. So I do not want to copy the .dll in each application bin folder. therefore I need to refer to a single .dll file from several application. Is it clear now? Every  naive programmer knows how to add a reference in vs! Anyway thank you for your participation.

Comment: This app.config you've posted. Where is it located?

Comment: I do not want to copy the .dll in each application bin folder. Doesnt this mean you need it in global cache?